# Activerecord query model for empty relation

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following classes/relationships:

```
#post.rb
belongs_to :user

#user.rb
has_many :posts
```

I need to do something like this:

```
scope :has_posts, joins(:posts).where('posts is not empty')
```

or something like:

```
User.where('posts is not empty')
```

What is the correct syntax for queries on relations? Can I do this efficiently without using a counter cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in user.rb:

```
scope :has_posts, :conditions => "users.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM posts)"
```

in controller:

```
User.has_posts
```